Problem in parsing PDF with tabula: dataframe has all data in one column
Hopefully someone can give me hints here.
I am parsing a remote PDF via tabula. All data is being downloaded fine, but somehow the extracted dataframe has all the information of the table in one column.
I am guessing I need to add some settings, but I don't know how.
Here's my code:
    import tabula
    pdf_path = 'https://disclosures-clerk.house.gov/public_disc/ptr-pdfs/2024/20025679.pdf'
    df = tabula.read_pdf(pdf_path, pages='1', lattice=True, multiple_tables=True)
    print(df[0].dropna(subset='ID'))

From the output you'll see that some how tabula does not find the separators between columns, as all the data of the first table is compressed in one row.
Could anyone provide some suggestions?
Thanks
Marco

Hello KJ apologies but i am a noob in PDF parsing and have just recently tried camelot and tabula to parse the link i posted in the message.  the PDF to me shows 8 columns..   i dont need a dataframe out of it, just the data in every single column.  also i have to parse the PDF programmatically. I suppose i need to play around with GUI first to find out the 'correct settings' to pass to tabule. thanks  for your help

Thanks a lot K J for useful info.. that's unfortunately the data I need to deal with... Kind regards
